# react cannot re-render when state change in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am starter in react & redux. I want to make todolist app. but when I insert a list into a store the displayList() function is not re-render. How can I fix this.

This is my reducer code.

```js
export default function(state = ['start1','start2'], actions) {
 switch(actions.type) {
  case 'APPEND_ITEM':
   state.push(actions.payload.item)
   return state
   break
 }
 return state
}
```

And this is my todolist.js code.

```js
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React from 'react'

class TodoList extends React.Component {
 displayList(){
  return this.props.dispatchs.map((item) => {
   return(
    <li key={ Math.random() }>{item}</li>
   )
  })
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    { this.displayList() }
   </div>
  )
 }
}

var mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  dispatchs: state.dispatch
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)
```

[pin 2,3 does not re-render on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9H9k.png)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using push in the reducer, return [ ... state, action.payload.item ]

```
case 'APPEND_ITEM':
    return [ ...state, action.payload.item ]
```

This is because React will see the new state (object reference) equal to the old one, and decide not to re-render since it seems like nothing have changed

Comment: @ChunRapeepat and if you are still not very familiar with the spread operator, then try to replace `push()` with `concat()`. Remember, no mutations in Redux :)

Comment: Also please replace the `Math.random()` method in your todo list key and use the index of the array instead. Who knows whether a new todo gets the same value as another one due to the "randomness" of `Math.random()`?